# What I need to use on Website and API Authentication in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication, authorization

I have a question. I seached some for authenticate users on API and Website Login/Register pages. I found 2 ways to authenticate users, first one is JWT Based, second one is Express Session Based. Which one do I should to use, why?
Thanks, have a beautiful day...

Comment: Stackoverflow shouldn't be considered a shortcut to avoid doing your own research. Answering this would require opinions and opinion based questions are off-topic here as outlined in the [help]

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, thanks for answer. So, I need to research about this topic myself, right?

Comment: Yes...of course

Comment: @charlietfl Alright, thanks.